# Unauthorized Message,Status 200 OK

Tags: c#, postman

I am doing the backend according to the given architecture given by the company I recently started working. 
I am new to C# and now I'm trying to do some post/get/put methods for some api-s.
There is a problem which I couldn't solve it.
Postman says:
 {
    "code": 1,
    "message": "Unauthorize"
} 
But the status code is 200 OK.

**UserController.cs**

```
[Route("v1/users")]
[Produces("application/json")]
public class UserController : BaseController
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Get list of users (Authorize)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// </returns>
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(BaseResponseModel<List<UserResource>>), 200)]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var user = await _userService.GetUserResourcesAsync();

        return Success(user);
    }
 }
```

This doesn't make any sense, or am I so dumb to realise the problem?
I have a login method and I can login, I get the success code, then I do this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovRph.png)
[Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDB3j.png)

**IProductService.cs**

```
    public interface IProductService
{
    Task<ProductDto>  GetAsync(int id);
}
```

**ProductService.cs**

```
        public async Task<ProductDto> GetAsync(int id)
    {
        var product = await _context.Product.SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == id);
        return _mapper.Map<ProductDto>(product);

    }
```

**ProductDto.cs**

```
 public class ProductDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public CategoryDto CategoryId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }

    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
 }
```

**Product.cs**

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Product : DomainModel<int>
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductCategoryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ProductCategoryId")]
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(256)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, DefaultValue(false)]
    public bool AllowEdit { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string CustomerCode { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There must be some headers or access token or something? Also, I suggest you to download the latest native app of Postman - https://www.getpostman.com/apps

Comment: I have updated the question can see the edit version? the header link?

Comment: This message is in the body, the body doesn't know anything about the header. They are set differently and not connected to each other. You can send correct data while statues is 404. You can as in your case send error message or wrong data with 200 OK Statues

Comment: You need to check the logic of the other function that returns the data of the users and set the statues of this web method according to the output of the other function

Comment: @SaIda - The code is working as expected as you have defined the `ProducesResponseType` on API. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute`, the attributed API actually defines what should be response code for specified types. See  the definition 
 of at [ProducesResponseTypeAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs).

**How it works**

Take following example which shows that the API throws the 404 error if the object is null:

```
public IActionResult GetById(string id)
{
    var post = <<Your logic here>>;
    if (post == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Json(post);
}
```

Now the same method can be changed to following, which would return 404 by using the `ProducesResponseType` instead of the code is being written in your API logic.

```
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
public IActionResult GetPostById(string id)
{
        var post = <<Your logic here>>;
        return Json(post);
    }
```

[image]

In cases, it might be good to also define a more explicit response type for successful calls. To do so, add a `ProducesResponseTypeAttribute` for status code with type. ( return type as parameter, which makes the Type property of Produces redundant).
This is valuable, if you want to return different things from one and the same method, for example, the following returns two different types depending on the returned status code:

```
[ProducesResponseType((int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Model), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
public IActionResult GetById(string id)
```

**What is your problem**

Now if you see your code which defines this attribute as `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BaseResponseModel<List<UserResource>>), 200)]`. And the code to fetch user :

```
var user = await _userService.GetUserResourcesAsync();
```

returns `BaseResponseModel<T>`. The BaseResponseModel should contain the `Code` and `Message` property. So here, the response returned by API is type of `BaseResponseModel<T>`, so API would return 200 HTTP Status as defined by attribute.

**How to Fix**

Either you return a different object in case of `Unauthorize` exception and attach the `ProducesResponseType` specific to that type OR handle the unathorized logic based at `Authorize` attribute.

Comment: Actually that was not the solution I was looking for. The fixing was by changing the authorization type to OAuth 2.0. But now I'm having another problem. Is saying an error that occurred during the activation of a particular registration. It says that None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type .ProductService. What does this error even mean?

Comment: That's the issue related to Dependency Injection.

Comment: yes I tried to fix it by adding this to Startup.cs:             builder.RegisterType<ProductService>()
                 .As<ProductService>();  but now another problem will show: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = ProductService (ReflectionActivator), Services = [..Service..IProductService] Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.CurrentScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration.

Comment: the first error was about "Cannot resolve parameter .. of constructor .." now is "No accessible constructors were found for the type .." after adding it to the startup file. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Can you please post the code which has error. The code you have provided was specific to `ProducesResponseType` so provided answer for that. Now, can you please post the scenario related to dependency injection so that people can suggest any specific changes around that.